# Function name visibility when declared as an argument

Tags: javascript

```
function foo() {
    ui.login.setClose(function closer() {
        ui.hideAll()
        ui.main.show()
    })
    ui.ask.setClose(closer) // <-- closer is not defined
    ui.adduser.setClose(closer)
}
```

I wonder why is this not working? Is not `function` keyword supposed to create a name visible anywhere within the  current function (foo) body?

Comment: That function is a callback, not a function declaration. You can define it first, then use it in both places.

Comment: That's **not a declaration**. It's a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is called a *named function expression*. (Don't use them in IE8 or earlier, or some other quite old browsers.) It's different from a function declaration in several ways, one of which is that (on a correct implementation) the function's name is not added to the scope in which you create it.

In that example, you probably want a function declaration instead, either inside `foo` if you only want it accessible within `foo`:

```
function foo() {
    function closer() {
        ui.hideAll()
        ui.main.show()
    }

    ui.login.setClose(closer);
    ui.ask.setClose(closer);
    ui.adduser.setClose(closer);
}
```

or outside `foo` if you want it accessible outside `foo`:

```
function closer() {
    ui.hideAll()
    ui.main.show()
}
function foo() {
    ui.login.setClose(closer);
    ui.ask.setClose(closer);
    ui.adduser.setClose(closer);
}
```

Here's the rundown of the three main ways you create functions (other than the `Function` constructor, which should almost always be avoided):

#### Function Declaration

Looks like this:

```
// `foo` is in scope *and* ready to use here, even before the declaration

function foo() {
    // `foo` is in scope and ready here too
}

// `foo` is in scope and ready here too
```

Characteristics:

1. Is **not** handled as part of the step-by-step code; instead, it's created before any step-by-step code in the scope is run. That means you could use `foo` above in code written *above* the declaration as well as below it.
2. Because of #1, a function declaration cannot be within control structures (like `if`, `switch`, `for`, etc.), since that's meaningless when the function will be created before the step-by-step code runs. (And it's important **not** to do it, as different browsers handle that invalid placement in *different* ways.)
3. Puts the name of the function in the scope where the function declaration appears.
4. The function has a real name, and that name is in scope *within* the function.

#### Named Function Expression

That looks exactly the same, except that it is written where an expression is expected, such as to the right of an `=` (e.g., an assignment) or `:` (in a property initializer) or as an argument to a function:

```
// `foo` is *not* in scope here

var x = function foo() {
    // `foo` is in scope here, refers to the function
};
var obj = {
    x: function foo() {
        // `foo` is in scope here, refers to the function
    }
};
bar(function foo() {
    // `foo` is in scope here, refers to the function
});

// `foo` is *not* in scope here
```

Characteristics:

1. They *are* handled as part of the step-by-step code, just like any other expression.
2. They work correctly on **modern** browsers (including IE9 and higher), but [there are bugs](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) in IE8 and earlier, and some other quite old browsers had bugs as well ([kangax wrote them up at the time](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)).
3. Being expressions, they have a result: A function reference. (E.g., that's what gets assigned to `x` or passed to `bar` above.)
4. Their name is **not** added to the scope where they're defined.
5. The function has a real name, and that name is in scope *within* the function (e.g., for recursion).

#### Anonymous Function Expression:

The same as named function expressions, but, er, without names:

```
var x = function() {
    // ...
};
var obj = {
    x: function() {
        // ...
    }
};
bar(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Characteristics:

1. They are handled as part of the step-by-step code, just like any other expression.
2. They result in a function reference (e.g., that's what gets assigned to `x` or passed to `bar` above).
3. The function doesn't have a name as of the current specification. However, the next specification, ES6, will have engines infer the name of the function *where possible* by looking at the expression. In the above, for instance, both of the ones that are assigned to `x` would have the name `x`; the one passed into `bar` would still be anonymous.

Comment: if name is not added to the scope in which I create it, why the naming is allowed anyway?

Comment: @exebook: For use *within* the function, for recursion. I've expanded to talk about declarations and expressions (named and anonymous).

Comment: Can you please explain how name `foo` in this example `bar(function foo() {...});` can be referred/used at all? You mentioned something about recursion, but I do not get it.

Comment: @exebook: `bar(function foo(x) { if (x > 0) { foo(x - 1); } })` If `bar` calls `foo` with `x = 10`, `foo` will call itself with `9`, which will call itself with `8`, and so on until `x` is `0`. That's recursion. Particularly useful for traversing tree structures or doing a brute-force calculation of a factorial. `foo` is in scope *within* `foo`, but not outside it.

Comment: I accept the answer, but I think your last commentary is what wanted to know originally.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to declare it as a function, not just a callback function.

Something like this:

```
function foo() {
    function closer() {
        ui.hideAll()
        ui.main.show()
    }
    ui.login.setClose(closer);
    ui.ask.setClose(closer) // <-- closer is not defined
    ui.adduser.setClose(closer)
}
```

Comment: The OP's code doesn't have an "anonymous callback".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, I'll adjust that

Answer (score 1):

In this case

```
setClose()
```

is excepting a function as an argument which in your code is only defined inside () and thus it is not available outside of setclose(). This way of defining a function  is typically used if the function  is only needed in the argument. That is why in this case, in principle, you dont need to specify a name  for it:

```
ui.login.setClose(function() { ui.hideAll(); ui.main.show(); });
```

However, in your case, you have to define the function closer() independently of the function setclose():

```
function closer() {
   ui.hideAll();
   ui.main.show();
}

function foo() {
   ui.login.setClose(closer);
   ui.ask.setClose(closer);
   ui.adduser.setClose(closer);
}
```

You additionally missed some ; to end the line.